# Where did Madara got his left eye after giving both of his real eyes to Nagato?

Tags: naruto

Madara said that he gave his real eyes to Nagato during his meeting with Obito, and that his current left eye was implanted recently.

Where did he get that eye?

Comment: Did you not see the massive stockpile of eyes that Obito had when he was convincing Sasuke to implement his brother's eyes?

Comment: @JoeW he could've (and probably have) collected those eyes during the Uchiha massacre, which happened after Madara's death.

Comment: I may be wrong but I would assume that the collection of eyes did not start with massacre of the clan.

Answer (score 2):

Madara had a huge stockpile of Sharingan, presumably collected from the bodies of various Uchihas over the many years he has been alive.

I would expect he used one of these, and that the reason he collected so many is so that he can use Izanagi and other techniques that cost the user an eye quite freely.

Comment: Again, we say Tobi with that stockpile, and it's very possible that he took it from the Uchiha Massacre which happened after Madara died, do you have sources to verify your claim?

Answer (score 0):

Madara's original eyes get blinded after using mangekyo sharingan too much. Then he get the eyes of his his brother Izuna from izunas corpse. Then eternal mangekyo sharingan activated. When he was defeated by hashirama, he uses the izanagi in exchange of his right eye to bring him back to life. Before hashirama killed him, he bite on hashirama's arm, he uses the flesh of hashirama to heal his wound, hashirama's dna activated the rinnegan. (Madara is reincarnation of Indra and hashirama is reincarnation of asura. sons of hagoromo otsusuki.) The combination of their dna awakens the rinnegan. After madara gave his eyes to nagato. He told obito that his right eye is from someone. But he didnt mention who it is.